# Как правильно организовать процесс развертывания с Docker (node.js, linux)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, развертывание

Плаваю в понятиях по этой теме и полного понимания процесса у меня нет, хочу его обрести. И так, есть виртуальный сервер с Ubuntu, есть приложение на Node.js + MySql. Для разработки собрал вот такой docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    links:
      - node:node
    volumes:
      - ./public:/usr/src/public
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  mysql:
    build:
      context: ./mysql
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysq
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  node:
    build:
      ./node
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=dev
      - NODE_PATH=/usr/src/app
    command:
      nodemon -L --inspect=0.0.0.0:5555 ./index.js
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
      - "8080"
    volumes:
      - ./node:/usr/src/app
      - ./public:/usr/src/public
    links:
      - mysql
```

**mysql/Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql:5.7

ADD my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf

RUN chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql/

ARG MYSQL_DATABASE=default_database
ARG MYSQL_USER=default_user
ARG MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
ARG MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQL_DATABASE
ENV MYSQL_USER=$MYSQL_USER
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

CMD ["mysqld"]
EXPOSE 3306
```

**nginx/Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

**node/Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN yarn global add nodemon mocha

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN yarn install

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Локально все это запускается и работает. Теперь предположим, что это должно крутиться на сервере, смотреть во внешний мир, перезапускаться, если вдруг упадет, быть удобоваримым для внесения правок и дальнейших доработок, ну и т.д. Может мне кто-нибудь объяснить, как новичку, из каких шагов состоит процесс? Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю разбить этот вопрос на несколько и задавать их по отдельности по мере возникновения проблем.

Сейчас отвечу тезисно:

1. Смотреть во внешний мир - это системное и/или сетевое администрирование. Если сам хост имеет внешний IP и правила firewall не закрывают порты 80, 8080 и остальные из секций ports, то сервисы будут доступны. Иначе многое зависит от того, как и где установлен сервер.
2. Перезапускаться - добавьте для каждого сервиса секцию:

```
restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure # или always
```

3. Правки приложения можно вносить в приложение и они сохраняться, так как приложение у вас находится вне контейнера в каталоге `./node`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Хочу немного уточнить вопрос внесения правок. Правильно ли я понимаю, что алгоритм такой? 1. вношу правки, заталкиваю их в репозиторий. 2. стягиваю правки на сервере. 3. делаю docker-compose restart?

И еще, сейчас в docker-compose.yml захардкожено `- NODE_ENV=dev`. Можно как-то передавать этот параметр из командной строки при запуске docker-compose up?